# List comprehension without using an iterable

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to build a list by picking random elements from another list with no duplicates. Think shuffling a pack of cards. I could obviously write some unpythonic code for this, which I dont want to.

So here is what I am trying to do:

`new = [deck[i] where 0<(i = some_rand_int)<51 if new.count(deck[i]) == 0]`

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: how about `random.shuffle()` ?

Comment: For starters, what would defined how many times this is executed?

Comment: @alexvassel FFFFUUUUU. Thanks though! Still curious if this can be done using list comprehension though!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I am trying to build a list by picking random elements from another list with no duplicates.

Use [`random.sample`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample):

> **random.sample(population, k)**
>
> Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence. Used for random sampling without replacement.

Try this:

```
result = random.sample(deck, n)
```

---

To shuffle the entire list use [`random.shuffle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

```
random.shuffle(deck)
```

---

> Still curious if this can be done using list comprehension though!

Not really. A list comphrension preserves the order of the elements, but allows you to project them or filter them. Shuffling is not a projection or a filter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use generators for this:

```
import random

def pick(deck):
    while True:
        try:
            newCard = random.choice(deck)
            deck.remove(newCard)
        except:
            print 'deck is empty...'
        yield newCard

def resetDeck():
    deck = []
    newCard = None
    for i in range(1,53):
        deck.append(i)
    return deck
```

pick(deck) picks a card from deck and if you wanted to recreate the deck use resetDeck().
after implementing, use pick(deck).next() to choose card from deck.